# pd.to_datetime is not converting date when it is zero

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
telecom["date_of_last_rech_data_6"].head()
0     6/21/2014
7             0
8             0
21            0
23            0
Name: date_of_last_rech_data_6, dtype: object

for col in date_cols:

    telecom[col] = pd.to_datetime(telecom[col])

telecom["date_of_last_rech_data_6"].head()
 0     2014-6-21
 7     1970-01-01
 8     1970-01-01
21     1970-01-01
23     1970-01-01
```

Please help me why pd.to_datetime is not converting the date when it is zero.

Comment: Which date are you expecting?

Comment: It looks normal to me, you get `1970-01-01` for the `0` values. What do you expect?

Comment: Nevermind. I understood now. Thanks for prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the error you get, however, check if the col values are numeric for those zeroes. String values can invoke errors.

e.g.

`['6/21/2014',0,0]` won't be an issue. `['6/21/2014','0','0']` will be an issue.